# Can a mover indefinitely delay the delivery?

Tags: united-states

I made a cross country move recently from OH to WA. Moving of household items were contracted to a company and they subleased the job to a mover based out of IL.

It has been more than two mo this now since the items were picked up and I still don't have them. Every time I call, I am told that it would be on the next truck to WA and refuse to provide any information on when that would be.

My question is:

- Are moving companies allowed to delay the delivery indefinitely like this?
- Is there anything I can do legally?
- Can I complaint to Police?

[ I know that FMCSA complaint is an option. But that doesn't guarantee anything.]

Comment: What does your contract say?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert "Agreed pickup/ Delivery periods: The first date indicated as available for delivery is the first date of the delivery window and not the promised delivery date. Pick up and delivery dates are not guaranteed."

Comment: The contract doesn't say any date. But on phone I was told that they will take 7-21 days from the date I provided the delivery address.